# Cloud Datastore avoid exploding indexes on very simple table

Tags: indexing, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, data-modeling

I'm trying to use Google Cloud Datastore to store METAR observations (airport weather observations) but I am experiencing what I think is exploding indexes. My index for `station_id` (which is a 4 character string) is 20 times larger than the actual data itself. The database will increase by roughly 250 000 entities per day, so index size will become an issue.

**Table**

```
 - observation_time (Date / Time) - indexed
 - raw_text (String) (which is ~200 characters) - unindexed
 - station_id (String) (which is always 4 characters) - indexed
```

**Composite index:**

```
  - station_id (ASC), observation_time (ASC)
```

**Query**

The only query I will *ever* run is:

```
query.add_filter('station_id', '=', station_icao)
query.add_filter('observation_time', '>=', before)
query.add_filter('observation_time', '<=', after)
```

where `before` and `after` are datetime values

**Index sizes**

```
name               type         count         size      index size
observation_time   Date/Time    1,096,184     26.14MB   313.62MB    
station_id         String       1,096,184     16.73MB   294.8MB
```

**Datastore reports:**

```
Resource           Count        Size
Entities           1,096,184    244.62MB
Built-in-indexes   5,488,986    740.63MB
Composite indexes  1,096,184    137.99MB
```

**Help**

I guess my first question is: What am I missing? I assume I'm doing something un-optimized, but I can't figure out what. Query time is not an immediate issue here, as long as lookups stays below ~2s.

Can I simply remove the built-in indexes, will the composite continue to work?

I've read up on Google and StackOverflow but can't seem to wrap my head around this. The reason I simply don't try to remove all built-in indexes is that it takes quite some time to download/un-index/put all the data afterwards I need to way 48hours for the dashboard summary to update - ie it will take me days before I get a result.

Comment: So I tried removing all the indexes, and keep the composite index. This doesn't however appear to work - the index is created but both size and entries are simply marked as "-"

Comment: Exploding indexes only happen when you are storing multiple values in a single property.  Does the code store multiple values in a single property, for example, multiple observation times in a single entity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As +Jeffrey Rennie pointed out, "Exploding Indexes" is a very specific term that does not apply here.

You can see how storage size is calculate from [our documentation here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/storage-size), so you can apply it to your example to see where the size adds up.

**TL;DR:** You can save space by using slightly more concise (but still readable!) property names. For example, `observation_time` to `observation`, etc

Key things to keep in mind:

- To have a composite index, you need to have the individual properties indexed, so don't remove the built-ins or it'll stop working
- Built-ins are indexed twice - once for ascending and once for descending
- Kind names and property names are strings used in the index for each entity, so the longer they are the bigger the indexes

Comment: Apologies for the sloppy title name. Thank you for the link and tips. I guess there is no way to disable the double ascending/descending indexing for built-ins?

Comment: I shorted all my property names and it saved me 42% of storage. Thank you Dan!

Comment: Glad it helped, @NiklasB :D